# Сохранить статус listview

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте.

Есть listview, в нем отображается галерея - картинка и текствью, по нажатию воспроизводится анимация и отображается еще одна картинка и текст, нужно сохранить статус при смене ориентации.

Адаптер вызывается из фрагмента:

```
public class AppCardsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//    private final LinearLayout.LayoutParams ivLp;
private final int height;
private AppList apps = new AppList();
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Fragment fragment;
private Context context;
private AbsListView.LayoutParams lp;
private Shimmer shimmer;
private final ImageLoader imageLoader;

private Animation animation2;
private Animation animation1;

public AppCardsAdapter(Fragment fragment, int height, AppList apps) {
    this.apps = apps;

    for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
        App app = apps.get(i);
        Log.i("AppCardsAdapter",
                i + ":app " + app.getNameEn() + " category " + app.getCategory());
    }
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.height = height;
    context = fragment.getActivity();
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height * 2 / 3);
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.to_middle);
    animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.from_middle);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return apps.size();
}

@Override
public App getItem(int position) {
    return apps.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return apps.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final App app = getItem(position);

    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_app_icon);
        holder.tvName = (ShimmerTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_name);
        holder.tvDescription = (RobotoTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_description);
        holder.hListView = (HListView) view.findViewById(R.id.hlv_app);
        holder.btnMarketUrl = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_market_url);
        view.setTag(holder);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    if (app.isFrontSide()) {
        lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height * 2 / 3);
        holder.btnMarketUrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
        holder.btnMarketUrl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString();
    if (locale.equals("ru_RU")) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(app.getDescriptionRu())) {
            holder.tvDescription.setText(app.getDescriptionRu());
        } else {
            holder.tvDescription.setText(app.getDescriptionEn());
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(app.getNameRu())) {
            holder.tvName.setText(app.getNameRu());
        } else {
            holder.tvName.setText(app.getNameEn());
        }
    } else {
        holder.tvDescription.setText(app.getDescriptionEn());
        holder.tvName.setText(app.getNameEn());
    }
    shimmer = new Shimmer();
    shimmer.start(holder.tvName);

    AppIcon appIcon = app.getAppIcon();
    if (appIcon != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(appIcon.getPath())) {
        imageLoader.displayImage(appIcon.getPath(), holder.ivIcon);
        holder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.ivIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    final int firstVisiblePosition = app.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    if (firstVisiblePosition != 0) {
        holder.hListView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("", "app = " + app.getNameEn() + ", firstVisiblePosition = " + firstVisiblePosition);
                holder.hListView.setSelection(firstVisiblePosition+1);
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    AppAdapter appAdapter = new AppAdapter(fragment, app, height);
    holder.hListView.setAdapter(appAdapter);

    holder.hListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsHListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsHListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == 0) {
                Log.e("", "app = " + app.getNameEn() + ",set firstVisiblePosition = " + firstVisiblePosition);
                app.setFirstVisiblePosition(view.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                apps.set(position, app);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsHListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                             int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
    final String marketUrl = app.getMarketUrl();
    if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(marketUrl)) {
        if (marketUrl.startsWith("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?")) {
            holder.btnMarketUrl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_get_on_market);
            holder.btnMarketUrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final String appPackageName = marketUrl.substring(
                            marketUrl.indexOf("=") + 1);
                    try {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                        + appPackageName)));
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.btnMarketUrl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_app_external_url);
            holder.btnMarketUrl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(marketUrl)));
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        holder.btnMarketUrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    view.setId((int) app.getId());
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            animation1.setAnimationListener(createListener(v, app));
            animation2.setAnimationListener(createListener(v, app));
            v.clearAnimation();
            v.setAnimation(animation1);
            v.startAnimation(animation1);
        }
    });
    return view;

}

public int getCategoryPosition(long id) {
    for (App app : apps) {
        if (app.getCategory() == id)
            return apps.indexOf(app);

    }
    return 0;
}

Animation.AnimationListener createListener(final View card, final App app) {

    final TextView tvName = (ShimmerTextView) card.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_name);
    final TextView tvDescription = (RobotoTextView) card.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_description);
    final HListView hListView = (HListView) card.findViewById(R.id.hlv_app);
    final ImageButton btnMarketUrl = (ImageButton) card.findViewById(R.id.btn_market_url);

    final boolean isFrontOfCardShowing = app.isFrontSide();

    Animation.AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (animation.equals(animation1)) {
                if (isFrontOfCardShowing) {
                    btnMarketUrl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    btnMarketUrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tvDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                card.clearAnimation();
                app.setFrontSide(!isFrontOfCardShowing);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                card.setAnimation(animation2);
                card.startAnimation(animation2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    };
    return listener;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView ivIcon;
    public HListView hListView;
    public ShimmerTextView tvName;
    public RobotoTextView tvDescription;
    public ImageButton btnMarketUrl;
}

}
```

Comment: Для чего вы хотите сохранять статус?

Comment: для видимости элементов